# Java shifting letters and restarting from a when past z

Tags: java, encryption

I want to shift text to encrypt it however i dont know how to restarte from the beginning (a) when going past z so if i input xyz and shift it 1 place it will give me yz( and not yza This is what i have done so far:

```
 System.out.println(" Input the ciphertext message : ");
         
            String ciphertext = sc.nextLine();
             System.out.println(" Enter the shift value : ");
             int shift = sc.nextInt();
             String decryptMessage = "";
             for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++)

             {
                // Shift one character at a time
                char alphabet = ciphertext.charAt(i);
                
                // if alphabet lies between a and z
                if (alphabet >= 'a' && alphabet <= 'z') 
                {
                   // shift alphabet
                   alphabet = (char)(alphabet + shift);

                // shift alphabet less than 'a'
                if (cAlphabet < 'a')
                {
                    //reshift to starting position
                    cAlphabet = (char)(cAlphabet - 'a' +'z' + 1);
                }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [modulo operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-or-remainder-operator-in-java/)

Comment: How would i use the modulo operator in this instance to restart from a, thanks

Comment: You know how to use `if`, can you figure out a condition for "I overshot z"? Then subtract z, add a, maybe fix up by +-1 (I dunno, experiment) and that should be it.

Comment: Hi i am new to java so this is tricky for me lol but i have been trying to experiment hopefully i can figure it.